# Android FB API 3.0 - application is misconfigured for Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm having issues with FB API.

On Friday morning, I've finished setting it up, and it worked fine I was able to install it on my 2 different devices and it worked on both.

On Sunday when I wanted to show my app to my friends, connection to Facebook crashed on device with FB app installed, and today for the first time with API 3.0 I saw that my app is misconfigured for Facebook login.

I did not touch the code till today, and the only thing I changed today is call where I publish image with caption, so I did not touch Login part at all:

```
if (MyGlobals.INSTANCE.isOnline(getSherlockActivity())) {
if (txt.getTag() == faceLoggedIn) {
 if (session.isOpened()) {
  Log.w("ss", "Session Allready Open");
  onClickLogout();
  updateSocialView(txt, img);
  // txt.setText("Log To Facebook");
  // txt.setTag(faceLoggedOut);
  // img.setImageResource(R.drawable.facebook_icon_gray);
  // MyGlobals.INSTANCE.f_socialsSet = false;
 }
} else if (txt.getTag() == faceLoggedOut) {
 if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
  Log.w("Session is not opend", "Session is not closed");
  session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(getActivity()).setCallback(MyGlobals.INSTANCE.statusCallback));
 } else {
  Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), true, MyGlobals.INSTANCE.statusCallback);
  Log.w("Open Active Session", "Status Callback");
  updateSocialView(txt, img);
 }
 updateSocialView(txt, img);
 // txt.setText("Log To Facebook");
 // txt.setTag(faceLoggedOut);
 // img.setImageResource(R.drawable.facebook_icon_gray);
 // MyGlobals.INSTANCE.f_socialsSet = true;
}
```

So what can cause this misconfiguration? How can App work one day, and then it does not work any more? I did remove the app from facebook to test how it behaves on first app download / login, but again I did not change the app preferences on FB platform.

If there is no FB app on device, everything works fine, webview appears, you log in, you post to FB, all set.

I'm totally confused what is wrong with it when there is FB app set up?

Please explain. Tnx.

Comment: Did you change the keystore that Android uses to sign your app? That's the most common cause of that error. If you change the keystore (either to a different one, or from debug to release), you also need to update the key hash for your app in app settings.

Answer (score 5):

When you are signing with the default android debug key, that key hash can change if a) the key expires and your IDE automatically creates a new one or b) you ran/built the app on a different machine (which has a different key hash from the one listed on your dashboard).

TL;DR: You have a mismatch on the key hash

To fix this, read our documentation here (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sig).  There are two methods to retrieve your key hash.  Everytime you use a different key to sign your app (whether that is because you are using another computer, or because your old debug key expired), you need to add it to your dashboard.  When you finally upload your app to Google Play, you have to create your own keystore file to sign it, and when you do that, don't forget to add the key hash of that keystore file to your dashboard.

Comment: Thank you Jesse, Yes I did build the apk file on a different machine, so yes it all worked on a machine where I built FB app, and it does not work on other so most likely I need to read this doc and sign it properly. Will check it out but your explanation clear things up for me. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer if its correct so other users know that they can use this solution for your issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jesse, as soon as I try and make sure that it works, I will accept the answer. I gave vote up because it sound reasonable, but I'm still finishing up some other things. Tnx.

Comment: There's really really a problem with key hashes. Misconfigured app is very very common. Please do something about it

Comment: Key hashes are a necessary evil that helps protect developers like you.  Without it, other apps can impersonate your app and make calls to FB stealing your user's data or performing malicious activity on your behalf.  By requiring key hashes, it safeguards your app from other apps.